# BindException when trying to run dual projects

Tags: java

Trying to run 2 separate Vertx applications. They both connect to the same database. I am getting the following bind exception.

I am only using http server on one of the projects thus don't think the following even matters. But tried it anyway with no difference. The error seems to stem from the attempt to connect to DB or so I think based on the exception. How can I overcome this to be able to run both projects same time? Please advice. Thanks.

Passing in the following as an environment variable doesn't make a diff as expected:

```
http.port=8095
```

Neither does setting port in following way makes a diff.

```
    int port = 8095;
    DeploymentOptions options = new DeploymentOptions().setConfig(new JsonObject().put("http.port", port));
    vertx.deployVerticle("verticle.MyVerticle", options);
```

Exception:

```
Aug 31, 2020 6:28:37 PM io.vertx.ext.asyncsql.impl.PostgreSQLClientImpl
INFO: Creating configuration for localhost:4040
Aug 31, 2020 6:28:38 PM io.vertx.core.impl.launcher.commands.VertxIsolatedDeployer
INFO: Succeeded in deploying verticle
Aug 31, 2020 6:28:38 PM io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl
SEVERE: Unhandled exception
rx.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: Address already in use
    at rx.functions.Actions$NotImplemented.call(Actions.java:576)
    at rx.functions.Actions$NotImplemented.call(Actions.java:572)
    at rx.Single$11.onError(Single.java:1794)
    at io.vertx.rx.java.SingleOnSubscribeAdapter.lambda$call$0(SingleOnSubscribeAdapter.java:33)
    at io.vertx.rxjava.core.http.HttpServer$6.handle(HttpServer.java:312)
    at io.vertx.rxjava.core.http.HttpServer$6.handle(HttpServer.java:307)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpServerImpl.lambda$null$4(HttpServerImpl.java:350)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.executeTask(ContextImpl.java:320)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.EventLoopContext.lambda$executeAsync$0(EventLoopContext.java:38)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute$$$capture(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:404)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:495)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:905)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:130)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:563)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1332)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:488)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:473)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:984)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:259)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:366)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute$$$capture(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasksFrom(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:380)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:355)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:486)
    ... 3 more
```